# Why my or operator doesn't work?

Tags: c++, c++11, operators

Why can't I get the right string. What do I have wrong in the expression? I can't figure it out. I've stocked for hours.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main (){
string var = "y";
string constant ="y";

if ((var != constant )||( var != "n")){
cout << "error";
}
else {
cout << "right" // this is what it should print
}
}
```

I understand that or operator uses || as symbol. So why can't my program perform its task

Comment: What's the expected result? The code will print out "error", according to the `if` condition.

Comment: `var != "n"` is true, so the whole expression is true.

Comment: `var` can't equal two different things at once...

Comment: the expected result is right. Why can't I get it?

Comment: Why do you believe that's the expected result? Because it's not. See my answer.

Comment: You should use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: It is not clear what OP expects from the operator. We just know what he wants to have printed.

Comment: The OP explicitly references the "or" operator.

Answer (score 2):

Your program's results are correct.

Since `var` is set to "y", then the expression

```
var != "n"
```

is obviously true.

As such, the full expression

```
if ( .... || var != "n")
```

evaluates to true. By definition "anything OR true" is always true.

No matter how much you want your `else` statement to execute, it will not. Because it should not be.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your program(aside from the syntax error at line 14). Your testing if `var` and `constant` are not equal, **or** var does not equal `'n'`. The or statement works fine, because you're basically saying: `if (condition or true)`, which will always be true because if he or operator finds only one condition true it will return true.

I believe what you want is the and, `&&`, operator. It only returns true if both of its conditions are true.

That being said above, even with the `&&` operator your still going to have to change your code. Your error\bug makes no sense. You told your program:

```
#pseudo code

if(false and false)
    print error
else
    print ...
```

your program is simply obeying the rules you set. The `if` statement above your `else` statement will **never** be reached because the `if` statement will always evaluate to `true`.